# How do I redirect back to my main page after a delay from any page in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

For context, I've created an informative site for a kiosk on location, using Blazor WebAssembly.

What I want it to do is that when the kiosk goes without interaction for X number of minutes, it will redirect back to the home page.

I want this to be the case globally across the site, not just on a few pages.

Is there any advice on how to approach this?

Comment: Just spit-balling here, but could you create a base class for your pages that has a timer and the redirect code in it? Then with a little javascript magic you can invoke a method that resets the timer on any keypress or mouse move event.

Comment: Oh, I do like that. Shouldn't be too hard to add retroactively I don't think?
Add it to shared, have maybe only the script tag as needed and then inherit other pages from it, also as a spitball

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to this a while back for an idle timeout to log users out after 20 minutes of inactivity. It was actually a fairly simple process if I remember. Basically I set up an event listener to listen for clicks on the `<body>` of my document, which would update a value in the sessionStorage with the date time value of the last interacted time or the time that the click event was fired. Then in something like the MainLayout.razor I started a task that would read that value from the sessionStorage every second (or every 5 seconds, or whatever, its up to you) and compare it to the current time, and if the elapsed time was greater than or equal to a warning time (like 18 minutes), then I would display a warning that they were about to be logged out. Then if the time was greater than the logout time (20 minutes in my case) then I would log them out, or in your case you would call `{NavigationManager}.NavigateTo("/");` I put `{NavigationManager}` into the curly braces because it's not a static method, you need to get the reference to it from the dependency injection container, just in case that was confusing to anybody else.

Here is my code to reference:

`MainLayout.razor`

```
private int IdleTimeoutWarningMinutes = 18;
private int IdleTimeoutLimit = 20;
private bool ShouldCheckIdleTimeout = true;

private async void StartIdleTimeout()
    {
        while (ShouldCheckIdleTimeout)
        {
            var LastInteractionTime = await JS.GetLatestInteractionTime();
            var LastInteractionDuration = DateTime.Now - LastInteractionTime;
            if (LastInteractionDuration > TimeSpan.FromMinutes(IdleTimeoutWarningMinutes) && LastInteractionDuration < LastInteractionLimit)
            {
                if (ShouldShowTimeoutWarning)
                {
                    //Show Timeout Warning
                }
            }
            else if (LastInteractionDuration >= LastInteractionLimit)
            {
                //navigate to home page

            }
            else
            {
                //make sure that the warning is hidden here in case the user begins interacting again before the timeout, but before the warning shows.
            }
            StateHasChanged();
            await Task.Delay(IdleTimeoutCheckTime);
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }


 protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        JS.SetLatestInteractionTime(DateTime.Now);
        StartIdleTimeout();
    }
```

`index.html`

```
<body onclick="WindowClick(event)">
</body>


<script>

function WindowClick(ev) {
            //ev.preventDefault();
            sessionStorage.setItem("ULI", new Date(Date.now()).toJSON());
        }
</script>
```

In an extensions class add this extension method:

```
public async static Task<DateTime> GetLatestInteractionTime(this IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
        {
            try
            {
                string timeRaw = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getLastInteractionTime");

                DateTime result;
                DateTime.TryParse(timeRaw, out result);
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                return DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that you might want to make the value `ShouldCheckIdleTimeout` a variable that is in your state manager or something if you're using one, so that set it to false on your main page and true on every other page in the `OnInitialized()` method so that it doesn't keep redirecting after it is on the main page.